# Storing a global variable in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a json that I need to have accessible across all types of apps in GCP: dataflow, GKE etc.
Is there a functionality in GCP allowing to store it as a variable that would be global across all GCP apps?
I'm thinking of SecretManager, but it's only allowing 64Kib payload while I need more. Also, this data by nature is not a secret, so I don't want to create confusion.
I'm thinking of putting as a json file in GoogleStorage bucket for now.

I could build an API, but then I would need to support it which I don't want't do.
The goal is store it with GCP functionality to avoid building and supporting an additional application.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I recommend using Google Cloud Storage. Fast, cheap, and global.

Comment: Same. Cloud Storage is the best place for that.